# Lista sendo modificada sem implementação

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, grafo

Estou com um problema em que a lista que estou trabalhando está sendo modificada mesmo sem que haja passagem de valores para ela.

```
from random import *
from numpy import *   

m=2

lista_inicial=[[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]

lista_aux = []

lista_aux = lista_inicial

print "condiçao inicial", lista_inicial

probabilidade =[0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]

novo_elemento=[]

tamanho_lista_adjacencia= len(lista_inicial)

for i in range(m):

    valor_soma=[]

    aleatorio= random.random()

    soma=0

    for j in range(tamanho_lista_adjacencia):

        valor_soma.append(probabilidade[j])

        soma= sum(valor_soma)

        if(soma>=aleatorio):

            novo_elemento.append(j)

            lista_aux[j].append(tamanho_lista_adjacencia)

            break

novo_elemento.sort()

print "Lista auxiliar:", lista_aux
print "Lista Inicial:", lista_inicial
```

Como podem vê, mesmo não passando valores/implementando a `lista_inicial` ela está sendo modificada.

Não sei como resolver isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema ocorre no trecho abaixo:

```
lista_inicial = [[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]
lista_aux = []

lista_aux = lista_inicial # Aqui!
```

Ao fazer `lista_aux = lista_inicial` você está indicando que `lista_aux` aponta para `lista_inicial`, não é criado uma cópia, você está apenas adicionando outro nome que aponta para a lista original em memória.

Portanto, quaisquer alterações feitas em `lista_aux` também serão visíveis em `lista_inicial`.

Para copiar uma [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), em Python *2* e *3*, você pode usar o método [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy

lista_inicial = [[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]
lista_aux = copy.deepcopy(lista_inicial)
```

Uma outra alternativa, neste caso é:

```
lista_inicial = [[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]

lista_aux = [x[:] for x in lista_inicial]
```

Há outras formas de copiar uma [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), porém neste caso por tratar-se de uma [lista multidimensional](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list), podem não vir a funcionar adequadamente.

Comment: Obrigado ajudou bastante. Passei bastante tempo utilizando a igualdade como uma forma de copiar.